# Python zip folder without including './' (current directory)

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to zip the content of the `test` folder:

```
first.txt
pof/
pof/second.txt
```

If I `cd` into `test` then zip it using

```
zip -r folder.zip *
```

and check the resulting archive with

```
zipinfo folder.zip
```

I get this output:

```
Archive:  folder.zip
Zip file size: 7573 bytes, number of entries: 3
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx     6473 tx defN 16-Mar-11 10:19 first.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 16-Mar-11 10:20 pof/
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx     2841 tx defN 16-Mar-11 10:20 pof/second.txt
3 files, 9314 bytes uncompressed, 7113 bytes compressed:  23.6%
```

Everything seems to be working as expected but if I zip the same folder using

```
shutil.make_archive('folder', 'zip', 'test')
```

then check the archive with

```
zipinfo folder.zip
```

I get this output:

```
Archive:  folder.zip
Zip file size: 7497 bytes, number of entries: 4
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- defN 16-Mar-11 10:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- defN 16-Mar-11 10:20 pof/
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6473 b- defN 16-Mar-11 10:19 first.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     2841 b- defN 16-Mar-11 10:20 pof/second.txt
4 files, 9314 bytes uncompressed, 7113 bytes compressed:  23.6%
```

What I don't like is that the `./` is included in the zip archive generated by Python: how do I avoid this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you use.

Comment: `./` designates the archive itself, i.e. `folder.zip`. When you're in a normal folder you can refer to it via `./` relative path, e.g. `/home/user/test/` is the same as `/home/user/test/./` or even `/home/user/test/././././`. It's just a way of specifying the directory being listed when listing directory contents.

Comment: @LutzHorn I've already included it: `shutil.make_archive('folder', 'zip', 'test')`.
I've accepted your edit.

Comment: @Nikita I know but how can I avoid including that path in the resulting archive (something like the output of the `zip -r` command)?

Comment: @LMGTFY, I meant, that it might be just a displaying thing. What do you get, when you unzip that archive to some folder, what do you get there? If it's not just a displaying issue, then may be something like `shutil.make_archive('folder', 'zip', 'test', '.')` will help.

Comment: @Nikita If I unzip the Python generated archive with `unzip folder.zip` the dot folder isn't created because, of course, it's already present but I don't think this is just a displaying issue. Yesterday I tried specifying the `base_dir` path but the result is still the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that `test` is in an otherwise empty folder and zip that parent folder. `shutil.make_archive()` includes everything *in* the folder you designate, not the folder itself:

```
$ tree parent/
parent/
└── test
    ├── first.txt
    └── pof
        └── second.txt
$ bin/python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Feb 20 2016, 23:04:20)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.make_archive('folder', 'zip', 'parent')
'/.../folder.zip'
>>> ^Z
$ zipinfo folder.zip
Archive:  folder.zip   504 bytes   5 files
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 11-Mar-16 11:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 11-Mar-16 11:19 test/
drwxr-xr-x  2.0 unx        0 b- stor 11-Mar-16 11:19 test/pof/
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx        0 b- defN 11-Mar-16 11:19 test/first.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx        0 b- defN 11-Mar-16 11:19 test/pof/second.txt
5 files, 0 bytes uncompressed, 4 bytes compressed:  0.0%
```

You can't prevent `shutil.make_archive()` from including the `./` current directory however. Write your own directory walking in that case:

```
import os
import os.path
import zipfile

zip_filename = 'folder.zip'
base_dir = os.path.abspath('parent')

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "w",
                     compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    base_path = os.path.normpath(base_dir)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base_dir):
        for name in sorted(dirnames):
            path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
            zf.write(path, os.path.relpath(path, base_path))
        for name in filenames:
            path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                zf.write(path, os.path.relpath(path, base_path))
```

Comment: Sorry I rechecked the `zip -r` command I provided and it was wrong (different path): I've now edited my question to reflect this.
I tried what you suggested but the resulting archive still has the unwanted `./` path.

Comment: @LMGTFY: yes, the `./` entry will still be included. You can't prevent this with `shutil.make_archive()`. I've included a version that builds the zipfile for you without that path.

Comment: That's a great one (yesterday I tried something similar but failed). Is it possibile to let `zipfile` make an archive with paths starting from `base_dir` instead of the full ones `zipinfo` is now reporting?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LMGTFY: sure, use [`os.path.relpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to produce a relative path for the second argument to `zf.write()`.